# ExtJs 3. : How to add borders for the grid body cells(without gird header)

Tags: css, extjs, extjs3, extjs-grid

I want to add grid cell border without grid header so I add CSS class for gird.
this my CSS class

```
#table_id td {    
border-color: #A8A8A8 ;
border-style: solid ;
border-width: 1px ;
z-index: 55000 ;
}
```

Above CSS creates border for gird header. So how can I remove grid header cell border?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.app-Grid table tr.x-grid-row,
.app-Grid table tr td.x-grid-cell
 {
     height: 36px;
     border-color: #555;
 }
//app-Grid is the css class applied to your grid
```

Your grid :

```
 Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
        title: 'Service Request Types and Rates',
        height: 210, 
        cls: 'app-Grid', 
        columnLines: true
});
```

Comment: i add css class to my grid but don't add cell border.

Comment: 'MyEditorGrid3Ui = Ext.extend(Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel, {
    title: 'Service Request Types and Rates',
    height: 210,
    border: false,
    bodyStyle: 'border-color: #A8A8A8 ;\nborder-style: solid ;\nborder-width: 1px ;\nz-index: 55000 ;',
    cls: 'app-Grid',
    columnLines: true,
    hideBorders: true,
    bodyCssClass: 'app-Grid.',
    id: '',' is by grid